# Помогите ускорить код c++!

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста ускорить код, для этой задачи:

> Синхронизация (20 баллов)
>
> Группа из n спутников  расположена на координатной прямой в точках с координатами 1, 2, ... n. Каждый спутник характеризуется мощностью генерируемого им сигнала pi. Если спутник в точке xi имеет мощность сигнала pi, то все спутники, находящиеся на расстоянии не большем чем pi, могут получить сигнал с этого спутника. Сам спутник свой сигнал не получает.
>
> Для синхронизации работы, все спутники одновременно послали свои сигналы всем остальным спутникам, до которых их сигнал доходит. Требуется для каждого спутника определить от скольки других спутников он получил сигнал.
>
> Input format
>
> В первой строке находится число n -- количество спутников, 2 ≤ n ≤ 105. Во второй строке через пробел перечислены n целых чисел -- мощности соответствующих спутников. В i-ой позиции второй строки содержится мощность спутника, находящегося в точке i на координатной прямой. Все мощности -- целые числа в пределах от 1 до 109.
>
> Output format
>
> Вывести n чисел через пробел, характеризующие количество сигналов, полученных спутниками в процессе синхронизации. В i-ой позиции должно быть указано количество сигналов, полученных спутником, находящимся в точке i на координатной прямой.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> a(n, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int p;
        cin >> p;

        for (int j = max(0, i - p); j < min(n, i + p + 1); j++){
            a[j] += 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Могу посоветовать использовать parallel for

Comment: Поменяйте алгоритм. Попробуйте применить [дерево отрезков](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для каждого спутника создайте три структуры, содержащие:

```
{левая граница = pos[i] - power[i]; +1}
{pos[i]; 0}
{правая граница = pos[i] + power[i]; -1}
```

и объедините всё в один вектор или массив

Отсортируйте вектор по первому полю. При равенстве первого поля раньше идёт запись с +1.

Инициализируйте `active_count = 0`, пройдите по вектору.

Если второе поле ненулевое, добавляйте его к `active_count`

Если нулевое, то соответствующий спутник принимает данные с `active_count - 1` других.

Сложность `O(nlogn)` обусловлена сортировкой, проход по списку линейный.